# How to switch between two JPanels without CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I build a game in swing and I have two JPanels for menu and the game itself. I want to switch from the menu panel to the game panel and from the game to the menu using JButtons. but every time I switch from the menu to the game, I want to start over the game and send the name of the player from some textField in the menu panel. so I need to make now instance of the game panel. How can I do this?

Here's the menu panel:

```
public class MenuPanel extends JPanel {
    
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtName;

    public MenuPanel(JPanel panel) {
        setLayout(null);
        contentPane = panel;

        JButton btnStart = new JButton("Click to start the game");
        btnStart.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
                cardLayout.show(contentPane, "Game Panel");
            }
        });
        btnStart.setFont(new Font("Baskerville Old Face", btnStart.getFont().getStyle(), 25));
        btnStart.setBounds(290, 510, 290, 70);
        add(btnStart);

        txtName = new JTextField();
        txtName.setBounds(450, 460, 160, 20);
        add(txtName);
        txtName.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Enter your name:");
        lblName.setForeground(SystemColor.text);
        lblName.setFont(new Font("Bradley Hand ITC", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblName.setBounds(260, 460, 180, 20);
        add(lblName);

        JLabel lblGame = new JLabel("RUMMIKUB GAME");
        lblGame.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        lblGame.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblGame.setFont(new Font("Goudy Old Style", lblGame.getFont().getStyle(), 50));
        lblGame.setBounds(180, 100, 500, 140);
        add(lblGame);

    }
}
```

Here's the game panel:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton btnReturnToMenu;
    private TileButton[][] buttons = new TileButton[Constants.ROWS_IN_PLAYER_BOARD][Constants.COLUMNS_IN_PLAYER_BOARD];
    private JLabel lblHello;
    private TileButton btnThrownByPlayer;
    private TileButton btnThrownByOpponent;
    private Point clickedButton;
    private JButton btnPullFromPool;
    private JButton btnFinish;
    private Game game;

    public GamePanel(String firstPlayerName, String secondPlayerName, JPanel panel) {
        setLayout(null);
        contentPane = panel;

        clickedButton = null;
        game = new Game(firstPlayerName, secondPlayerName);

        lblHello = new JLabel("hello " + firstPlayerName + " and " + secondPlayerName);
        lblHello.setBounds(10, 10, 250, 40);
        add(lblHello);

        //initiate exit button.
        btnReturnToMenu = new JButton("Return To Menu");
        btnReturnToMenu.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
                cardLayout.show(contentPane, "Menu Panel");
            }
        });
        btnReturnToMenu.setFont(new Font("Mongolian Baiti", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnReturnToMenu.setBounds(10, 70, 200, 40);
        add(btnReturnToMenu);

        // initiate finish button.
        btnFinish = new JButton("Finish");
        btnFinish.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (btnFinish.isEnabled()) {
                    if (game.finish()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "You finish the game.\nCongratulations, you are the winner!!!");
                        CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
                        cardLayout.show(contentPane, "Finish Panel");
                    } else {
                        btnFinish.setEnabled(false);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't finish the game yet");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btnFinish.setFont(new Font("Mongolian Baiti", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnFinish.setBounds(750, 50, 100, 40);
        add(btnFinish);
    }
}
```

Here's the frame:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private GamePanel gamePanel;
    private MenuPanel menuPanel;
    private FinishPanel finishPanel;

    private MainFrame() {
        //super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(233, 55, 900, 627); 
        setResizable(false);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());

        menuPanel = new MenuPanel(contentPane);
        gamePanel = new GamePanel("", "", contentPane);
        finishPanel = new FinishPanel(contentPane);

        contentPane.add(menuPanel, "Menu Panel");
        contentPane.add(gamePanel, "Game Panel");       
        contentPane.add(finishPanel, "Finish Panel");

        getContentPane().add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: *"so I need to make now instance of the game panel."* No, you don't. Store the game attributes in a `GameModel`, create a new model (or refresh the existing one) then refresh the `GamePanel`. *"without CardLayout?"* Use a `CardLayout`. And.. `setLayout(null);` Use layouts generally. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and ..

Comment: .. borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: And while I'm here. Don't extend `JFrame` or `JPanel` when not changing functionality. Just use plain instances of them. Don't add a `MouseListener` to buttons, instead add an `ActionListener`. `new Font("Mongolian Baiti"..);` - you will need to supply that font with the app. and load it before it can be used. .. Whatever resource you have been using to write that code, dump it and do the [Trail: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Comment: Why don't you want to use a CardLayout? That would be the obvious solution.